# Is the alternating group $A_1$ empty?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm proving that $A_n$ is a subset of $S_n$. By definition, $A_n$ is the set of permutations in $S_n$ that can be decomposed into an even number of 2-cycles. Since $S_1$ has no 2-cycles, it seems that $A_1$ would have to empty.

If I'm right, then that would mean that $A_n$ is subgroup of $S_n$ only when $n\geq 2$. Since my textbook just asked to show that $A_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ without specifying that $n\geq 2$, I think that I'm wrong that $A_1 = \emptyset$. Some clarification would help me.

Comment: The identity is the product of $0$ transpotions, hence it is even.

Comment: A subgroup is never empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_1$ consists of the identity permutation, hence is equal to $S_1$. In fact, the identity permutation is contained in $A_n$ for all $n$ (this is important for the fact that $A_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$) because it is an empty product of transpositions.

Comment: Ok, so by transpositon, you mean that $e$ can be expressed as the product of 0 2-cycles?

Comment: Yes, that's right. There are also other equivalent definitions of even permutations which handle this case better. E.g. defining the sign of a permutation as $-1$ raised to the number of inversions.